# MATLAB not enough input argument error

Tags: matlab

Maybe i'm missing something obvious, but i'm just starting matlab so...

I have created many user defined function and use them to solve another function.
each function works when tested separately, but when I try test the bigger function, i get this message:

```
Error using F1 (line 2)
Not enough input arguments.


Error in run (line 5)
[X,Y]=NewrRaph2(F1,F2,d1x,d1y,d2x,d2y,1,1,iter)
```

my function `F1` is:

```
function [F1]=F1(x,y)
F1=4*x^2+y^3+28;
```

and my function `Newraph2` is:

```
function [X,Y]=NewrRaph2(F1,F2,d1x,d1y,d2x,d2y,x,y,iter)
x=x;
y=y;
for n=1:iter
deltax=((-F1(x,y)*d2y(y))+(F2(x,y)*d1y(y)))/Jacob(dix(x),d1y(y),d2x(x),d2y(y));
deltay=((-F2(x,y)*d1x(x))+(F1(x,y)*d2x(x)))/Jacob(d1x(x),d1y(y),d2x(x),d2y(y));
x=deltax+x;
y=deltay+y;
end
X=x;
Y=y;
```

also, to test my function I use this script:

```
clear, clc
x=input('valeur de x  ')
y=input('valeur de y  ')
iter=input('valeur de iter: ');
[X,Y]=NewrRaph2(F1,F2,d1x,d1y,d2x,d2y,x,y,iter)
```

But I don't understand what I did wrong.

Comment: You don't need to have the functions `F1` and `F2` as input parameters to `NewrRaph2`. I think that should solve the problem.

Comment: Also, there are a bunch of undefined variables here: `[X,Y]=NewrRaph2(F1,F2,d1x,d1y,d2x,d2y,x,y,iter)`.

Comment: the other variable are defined in my progragram but are not relevent for my question (they are user defined function similar to F1)

Comment: I tried your solution, but it still display the same error message after i run my programme. (plus my instruction were to put the variable F1 as an input argument, so we could change the function easiy if we wanted)

Comment: You need to tell us which data you are calling your function with, and also what the function `Jacob` is. If we don't have enough information to replicate the problem, we can't help you. Also, there is probably a typo in the `deltax` line: I assume you mean `Jacob(d1x(x),...)` instead of `Jacob(dix(x),...)`.

Comment: the function Jacob is: `function [J]=Jacob(d1x,d1y,d2x,d2y,x,y)
J=(d1x(x)*d2y(y))-(d1y(y)*d2x(x));`

Comment: Replace `[X,Y]=NewrRaph2(F1,F2,d1x,d1y,d2x,d2y,x,y,iter)` by `[X,Y]=NewrRaph2(x,y,iter)` when you define it, and when you use it, or, you could try `[X,Y]=NewrRaph2(@F1,@F2,@d1x,@d1y,@d2x,@d2y,x,y,iter)`

Comment: It is kind of hard to say exactly what is wrong here, but there are at least one thing that need give some attention to. In matlab it is possible to overload functions by using them as variables. However, if there is at least any possibility to avoid this you should, since these things always cause a royal mess. Also, a function defined in your matlab path (all places where matlab can read files) does not need to be used as input parameter to a function call and if not in path,they cannot be used anyway. Also, To be able to give you the exact cause of your trouble we must see the function call

Comment: I think that I also could give you some general practice in matlab. Normally you use matlab functions stored in .m files if there are functions that you think you will need some other time and you think will be cumbersome to call everytime you need it. These are typically functions that you do not do changes in so often. However, mathematical functions that are likely to change every call is often defined as **inline functions** (google it) and I assume that this is what you intended to use. These are defined locally in the file where you need them (and passed to other functions as arguments)